# Not getting token using FCM

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get push notification from the FCM notification console to my app just for testing and I am not getting token to initiate push notification on Single Device.
On User Segment its working (I am getting push notification using User segment option) but not for single device.

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {

    }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            String msg = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            sendNotification(msg);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.questionshield)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

**build.gradle(Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile files('glide-3.7.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**manifest file**

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: have you put `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in your project gradle inside dependencies

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the logs at all?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added below line in app level dependancies?

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

I was facing the same issue. After adding this lines in App level build.gradle i received Token.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) is the link to see the detail.

Comment: Yes. I have posted just relative things

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these line in launch activity

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("message");
    String token =  FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "FCM Token: "+token);
```

Comment: Gives error:    java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you create app in firebase console ? What is the server side code?

Comment: Yes, I have created it and I am trying to get it form console.

Comment: please check the package name in firebase console? is it same as project base package name

Comment: i have put this code in my mainactivity.java so i getting error on this

Comment: @IshanFernando Error is i m not got the every time FCM Token
so what i can do for getting every time getting Token?

Comment: It return null if the token not generate. but in the token refresh method we listen to the token generation. in that method you can get that token. If you need to retry you can add background task to retry if the token fail. @HardikParmar

Comment: @IshanFernando yes its working fine with background task like doinbackground task

Answer (score 0):

Your registered action is incorrect, please change your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Answer (score -2):

According to

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

```
onTokenRefresh()
```

only Called if InstanceID token is updated

So it will call only at first time when you install an app to your device.

So I suggest please uninstall your app manually and try to run again

definitely, you will get TOKEN

Comment: `onTokenRefresh()` isn't called *only at the first time you install an app to your device*. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService.html#onTokenRefresh())